# Navbar in Rails layout is not acting responsively using Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar

I'm using a Bootstrap theme (from [wrapbootstrap.com](http://wrapbootstrap.com)) with a Rails application, and the navbar is not acting responsively for some reason. The CSS is working for everything else except the responsive navbar.

With a traditional html file, it works fine but when I include it in a Rails layout (as seen below) it is not responsive and does not show the jQuery drop-down menu you traditionally see aligned to the right.

Here's how I'm including the js and css in the head of my layout, employees.html.erb

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "scaffolds.css.css", :media => "all" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap-responsive", :media => "all" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap-responsive.min", :media => "all" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap", :media => "all" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.min", :media => "all" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "main", :media => "all" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "style", :media => "all" %>

  <%= javascript_include_tag "bigvideo" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap.min" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.7.2.min" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min" %> 
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.imagesloaded.min" %> 
  <%= javascript_include_tag "modernizr-2.5.3.min" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "video" %>
```

Here's the navbar html that's in the body:

```
  <!-- Navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top"> 
  <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="brand scroller" href="index.html">Company Name</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                <li><a href="#" class="scroller" data-section="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="scroller" data-section="#process">PROCESS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="scroller" data-section="#team">TEAM</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="scroller" data-section="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="scroller" data-section="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any thoughts or suggestions regarding why the navbar is not acting responsively based on how the CSS and JS are included is very much appreciated.

Comment: My guess it has to be the theme your are using. Without more information, it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Apologies, I know it's hard to troubleshoot something like this w/o more. What additional info from the theme would be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, You don't need to add bootstrap (css and js files) twice, for example:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap-responsive", :media => "all" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap-responsive.min", :media => "all" %>
```

In this case `bootstrap-responsive` is the same that `bootstrap-responsive.min` but minified.

Secondly, try adding bootstrap responsive after bootstrap, maybe you are overriding some "responsive" styles:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap", :media => "all" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap-responsive", :media => "all" %>
```

Hope this helps!